# How to add logo to footer of fancy page and place it depending on odd or even page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use a `fancyfoot` of the `fancyhdr` package and let the footer text align left or right depending on the page number (odd or even).

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{footer text}
```

This is how it behaves now:

odd page:

```
                                 3                     footer text
```

even page:

```
  footer text                    4
```

Now I want to add a logo (logo.png) to this footer. This is what I have in mind:

odd page:

```
                                 3              footer text logo.png
```

even page:

```
  logo.png footer text           4
```

Is this possible in combination with `fancyhdr` package, and how?

Comment: `\fancyfoot[LE]{\includegraphics{logo.png}}`, should work, in my point of view. Please do not post fragments only, but a documen that can be compiled.

Comment: You have to split your stuff. `fancyfoot[LE]{logo~text}` and `\fancyfoot[RO]{text~logo}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change of the page from even to odd requires special setups if the order of the text etc. should be reversed.

Use `\fancyfoot[LE]{...}` and `\fancyfoot[RO]{...}` with the relevant content.

It should be possible to use a `\ifodd\value{page}...\else...\fi` approach too, but I've not tested this.

Please change the `\footskip` (there's a warning if it should be too small) and change the amount of skip in `\raisebox` (if needed at all?) at will.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente.jpg}} Ducks are cute}
\fancyfoot[RO]{Ducks are cute\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente.jpg}}}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer! It seems to work, but the logo stays very small. Any ideas about how to enlarge the logo?

Comment: @user1983395: I don't have your logo, so I don't know how large your `logo.png` is. You must use the `scale=...` option of `\includegraphics`, my file is pretty large, so I had to use `0.2` here. But I recommend to keep the `logo.png` small -- it's a logo and not the main content on your page. Consider also, that the logo file is included multiple times and will increase your document file size considerably. It's best to scale down the logo beforehand, i.e. reduce the `logo.png` and include that one!

Comment: I removed the scale parameter and my page looks perfect now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1983395: That's another possibility of course ;-)